# Adding Constant to RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a really stupid question, I know that a RDD is immutable, but is there any way that you can add a column of constant to a RDD?

More specifically, I have an RDD of RDD[a:String, b:String], I wish to add a column of 1's after it so that I have a RDD of RDD[a:Stirng, b:String, c:Int].

The reason is that I want to use the reduceByKey function to process these strings, and an arbitrary Int (that will be constantly updated) will help the function in reducing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do it with `map` function, here's an example in Python:

```
rdd.map(lambda (a,b): (a,b,1))
```

Comment: Great! thanks, I will try to find the syntax for scala!

Answer (score 4):

Solution in Scala is to use map simply

```
rdd.map( t => (t._1, t._2, 1))
```

Or

```
rdd.map{ case (a, b) => (a, b, 1)}
```